# INSERT IGNORE with invalid field value actually inserts Zero

Tags: mysql

I've in my table defined a field which is `NOT NULL`.

If I run a query `INSERT IGNORE` with `null` values *it inserts a row with zero value* instead of just ignoring the `null` value. (And the same happens even for values having invalid data type)

```
CREATE TABLE all_numbers (
    Numbers INT NOT NULL,
    AssociatedNumbers INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT IGNORE INTO all_numbers (Numbers, AssociatedNumbers)
    VALUES (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), (null, null);
```

And output is:

```
Numbers AssociatedNumbers
   1          2
   3          4
   5          6
   7          8
   0          0
```

Same is the case for:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO all_numbers (Numbers, AssociatedNumbers)
    VALUES (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8), ('a', 'b');
```

Any idea why is this happening, and how to make MySQL to just **ignore** invalid values specified in the query? (*Zeros instead of invalid value* is really undesirable!)

**UPDATE**

Even after I enabled `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` mode its still not working. Here are screenshots:

[image: Output of <code>SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;</code>]

[image: INSERT query output]

Comment: Share `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;`

Comment: After I added lines to enable the STRICT_ALL_TABLES in my.ini it show's the mode as output of `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;` However, it is still not working as expected. Please have a look at screenshots above, Thanks.

Comment: Yup still not working for me too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `IGNORE` is ignoring. It doesn't do value checking and ignore bad values, it just ignores or works around the errors that result from trying to insert those bad values. [From the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> Data conversions that would trigger errors abort the statement if IGNORE is not specified. With IGNORE, invalid values are adjusted to the closest values and inserted; warnings are produced but the statement does not abort. You can determine with the mysql_info() C API function how many rows were actually inserted into the table.

The "closest value" for a numeric column [is zero](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/constraint-invalid-data.html):

> If you try to store a string that does not start with a number into a numeric column, MySQL Server stores 0.
>
> …
>
> If you try to store NULL into a column that doesn't take NULL values… MySQL Server stores the implicit default value for the column data type. In general, this is 0 for numeric types…

As mentioned in another answer, [setting the mode to strict](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict) will prevent this behaviour. You can set this in your session at run time with this query:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
```

To do this on a server-wide basis, start MySQL with `--sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"` or add `sql-mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"` to your `my.cnf` configuration file.

Comment: I am sorry, this is still not working somehow. Despite enabling STRICT_ALL_TABLES it is still inserting those zeros. Please have a look at screenshots I added and advice me. Thanks.

Comment: Like I said, `IGNORE` will ignore errors. Set mode to strict, and just do a straight `INSERT`. You will have to have application logic to catch errors on insert, or filter invalid values before.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify:

Set sql_mode = "strict_all_tables";

This will have the check to be more strict and give the correct results.